# Eclipse not opening Websphere Liberty console

Tags: eclipse, websphere-liberty

I have a Websphere Liberty server installed in another computer that we use as a test server.

My Eclipse IDE is connected to it, i can upload projects/code. I also looked at the Liberty console in Eclipse to track errors.  But now Eclipse is not showing the console, i have the 'Console' tab (view), but nothing is showing.

Eclipse is still connected to the Liberty server, as i see it in the Server view, and am able to upload code.

I had restarted the Liberty Server and my Eclipse many times.

Any idea how can i connect to the console again ?

Thanks 
   SJRM

Answer (score 0):

I had noticed the console not displaying issue as well. For me it was an intermittent timing issue. It was fixed as of January of this year. Have you tried out the latest Beta version of the Eclipse tools? It fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Please use comment section to asking questions before answering.

Comment: Same as you. seems to be intermitent. The console was showing again yesterday... today it dissapeared again ... just after restarting the Liberty Server

Comment: I suspect you'll find it works consistently with the latest Beta.